# How to deny reading some pages in dokuwiki?

Tags: wiki, wikipedia, dokuwiki

I have a dokuwiki server for projects leading. I want to have some pages only for my eyes. How to deny access to some pages for some users? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Access Control List feature of DokuWiki. See https://www.dokuwiki.org/acl for more info